# How to encrypt different headings to different keys

Tags: org-mode, encryption

I'd like to encrypt different headings in my org file to different keys, e.g.,

```
* Heading 1
* Heading 2
```

where `Heading 1` should be encrypted to `me1@example.com` and `Heading 2` should be encrypted to `me2@example.com`, using gpg.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you find any answers about how to encrypt headings with different keys?

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt or decrypt the contents under headings using different keys you will need to set the `CRYPTKEY` property value to the `uid` of the desired key as listed in your key-ring.

1. Setup gpg key-ring as needed.

   For this example, let's imagine that both the public and secret keys are already setup in your key-ring.

   ```
   $ gpg --list-public-keys

   /home/melioratus/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
   --------------------------------
   pub   2048R/4F37FF8D 2018-11-17
   uid                  Me1 Example (Me1) <me1@example.com>
   sub   2048R/57F6928B 2018-11-17

   pub   2048R/9774ACC3 2018-11-17
   uid                  Me2 Example (Me2) <me2@example.com>
   sub   2048R/F5A8A9BA 2018-11-17

   $ gpg --list-secret-keys

   /home/melioratus/.gnupg/secring.gpg
   --------------------------------
   sec   2048R/4F37FF8D 2018-11-17
   uid                  Me1 Example (Me1) <me1@example.com>
   ssb   2048R/57F6928B 2018-11-17

   sec   2048R/9774ACC3 2018-11-17
   uid                  Me2 Example (Me2) <me2@example.com>
   ssb   2048R/F5A8A9BA 2018-11-17
   ```
2. Add the `CRYPTKEY` property under each heading with value equal to the `uid` of the desired key as listed in your key-ring. Also add the `crypt` tag to the heading.

   ```
   * Heading 1                                                           :crypt:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :CRYPTKEY: Me1 Example (Me1) <me1@example.com>
   :END:
   Heading 1 should be encrypted using the =me1@example.com= key.
   * Heading 2                                                           :crypt:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :CRYPTKEY: Me2 Example (Me2) <me2@example.com>
   :END:
   Heading 2 should be encrypted using the =me2@example.com= key.
   ```
3. Encrypt all the headings tagged with `crypt` using <kbd>M-x org-encrypt-entries</kbd>.

   After encryption, you should the outline should resemble the example below:

   ```
   * Heading 1                                                           :crypt:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :CRYPTKEY: Me1 Example (Me1) <me1@example.com>
   :END:
   -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

   hQEMA9teruFX9pKLAQf9FTEluginoTmDMkhufiZGziTCOeTbO0mGo3uVmLR8eUtf
   tmJEy3lbWJ7YHGoR/iIo/KqvglClZw9c0ZiPw3WWgMkei8gj+5g1Tcil7X+HnZYN
   XmG8Pmz5dkRidxlsUogNULnN7DbqA72Eyfuvd9gqwEqE9rtFGVB3VHtHBUHUAawO
   031DD7ou87oTPMPjQ7Z9BO14VrR2aSgbdqNttX1+zYTGpipRQ8F3ZewW1obvHEeD
   /gG+jMxYycs4SMnIPcXTPpc5r/RXb1fL4mmrbgPFkctuVBBTve7/gZsDsVqlchia
   /kQp/YQhTMKfk71naYEyHRDbCkzh+M+LJfaIMxcd7NJ5AR0U83qAsK6b6+1pDjGy
   sXukle3PeAMjBuzuF92j51RdseATNeixmL+qHeFr2btau0Wd5OGsa/4FG2GzRo9i
   VO8akmuDjfnCnP/EqefyawJPh9N/E32Bp+nz8T8iG7jRN5aGLrYJx5JWdaaQ6ScW
   PJ8o3b5AxNJyjQ==
   =NGp+
   -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
   * Heading 2                                                           :crypt:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :CRYPTKEY: Me2 Example (Me2) <me2@example.com>
   :END:
   -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

   hQEMA5w/LLn1qKm6AQf8DxC5CpGu/lWqQMWnKoA1XCH+PXAmJtaQCFUqQlecu7ZU
   UTPL1fb2i9uFkf3SW+eoewQ7NImp5tQqnTunoF2QA6yoc38BrodtGYPJQAIPBDUj
   nxHdGr+q1HuSn27jvs+fWHNSHWbp5ANvl4roDCm7nFAk0sf6SKOwgCAvHrQfqeq2
   5cHJIy6FlllpvWYhfWpjRwrrzRgEc8tVNQWL7RDPsKnP8DBXsIsODhjeBYYLkAHI
   iMnq1IkLTgS4LO5lwIsGcaz7VhBjlr27NhtISRyno3nvL+TsdXS7tnK4a+jE2wX/
   WeDNV3OlBz+t5BoSElfdh+S3dzyTUJpK9azMKPZxndJ5ATsmwSehDRduWG9xENDG
   G1PU8E8ye/vO3E2d3SnM0EtqmzRyQQCZXLaUjEyyRnWI5rakM+bY9MItfy055D34
   Nq0R3RFAVCay9TM3fK+hzM7fLWzApJUTVo42ezkA2pVM5qHh7GHLXnD/3ieI9Cop
   OXlZFJJbF7KHKA==
   =G7/l
   -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
   ```
4. To decrypt all the headings tagged with `crypt` use <kbd>M-x org-decrypt-entries</kbd>.

**Thanks for asking a great question!**

---

> **This answer was tested using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   org-mode version: 9.1.2
>   gpg version: gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.21